# How to show certain sub categories on a page

Tags: category, phtml

I have some code which displays certain categories on a page. I chose these categories by defining the category ID in an array, however if i put in a sub category ID the category is not displayed, this is my code.

```
<?php $arr_cat_ids = array('65','85','64','83','56','71');?>
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): 
$this_cat_id = $_category->getId();
if(in_array( $this_cat_id, $arr_cat_ids)){
?>
<?php $open = $this->isCategoryActive($_category); ?>
<?php
$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
if ($immagine = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()):
?>

<div class="catalog-image">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $immagine ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName()) ?>" class="img-responsive" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="left"><h2><a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>"><?php echo $_category->getName()?></a></h2></div> 
</div>
<?php endif; 
}?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

what would i have to change so i could show parent categories as well as sub categories?